# Is manual configuration always required when subscribing to Change Data Capture events via the Pub/Sub API?

Tags: platform-event, change-data-capture, event-monitoring, publish-subscribe

I'm creating an application that subscribes to events via the Pub/Sub API. So for example, I'm subscribing to `/data/AccountChangeEvent` to receive notifications of Account changes. For this to work on my Salesforce instance I have to go into `Setup > Change Data Capture` and move Account into the list. If I don't do this, I get an error when calling the Pub/Sub api to subscribe to this specific event.

Is there not a way to subscribe to events via the Pub/Sub API without this manual up-front configuration? The help text on this page says `Select the entities that generate change event notifications on the default **standard** channel` but I'm not subscribing to the standard channel, I'm subscribing to a **specific** channel. Seems odd.

I did try making this change programmatically via the metadata API but kept getting auth errors with the supplied OAuth access token, so not sure if it's possible or I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Subscription Channels](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_subscribe_channels.htm), it says:

> If you expect change events for only a single entity, use single-entity channels. With single-entity channels, you can subscribe to change events from only one custom object or standard object. Select the entity for notifications on the Change Data Capture page in Setup or in a custom channel.

Note the last sentence. You only get CDC events if CDC is enabled for the object, regardless of if you're using the standard channel or a single-entity channel.

You should be able to enable CDC for an entity with the metadata API using the [PlatformEventChannelMember](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_platformeventchannelmember.htm) object.